# Weighing Factors in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Report where I count quotes across countries and SubRegions. Now I have a number of quotes where the Country is null .

```
Table 
Quote Number | Country | Subregion | Quote Count 
12233        | Germany | EMEA      | 100 
2223         | Blank   | EMEA      | 3333
3444         | France  | EMEA      | 200
455454       | Spain   | EMEA      | 300
```

Total Quotes Without Null Countries say equals 1000, with 10% related to Germany etc. So Germany weighting factor is 0.1.

So in total I have 3333 quotes where the country field is blank. So  I have been asked to get the quotes for EMEA and just distribute the quotes across the countries like Germany, Spain, France and other EMEA countries using a weighting factor based on the current spread of Quotes and then add the quotes to the counts for the other countries in that Region like EMEA .

So at the moment I am completely confused in terms of how to do this ? Any ideas ?

Help ? Someone ?

Step 1 - Get current weighting factors for all countries in EMEA . In sql ?

Step 2  - Get the quotes count for quotes with no country assigned for EMEA . In sql ?

Step 3 - Take quotes and add x number of quotes to each country based on Weighing Factor. In sql ?

Comment: Quotes Numbers added to the number must be whole numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the data in your sample:

```
WITH    Factors
      AS ( SELECT   Country ,
                    SUM([Quote Count])
                    / CAST(( SELECT SUM([Quote Count])
                             FROM   dbo.quotes
                             WHERE  Region = q.Region
                                    AND Country IS NOT NULL
                           ) AS FLOAT) AS WeightingFactor ,
                    q.Region
           FROM     dbo.quotes q
           WHERE    country IS NOT NULL
           GROUP BY q.Country ,
                    q.Region
         )
SELECT  q.country ,
        ( SELECT    SUM([quote count])
          FROM      dbo.quotes
          WHERE     Country IS NULL
                    AND Region = q.Region
        ) * f.WeightingFactor + SUM(q.[Quote Count]) AS [Quote Count]
FROM    dbo.quotes q
        JOIN Factors f ON q.Country = f.Country
                          AND q.Region = f.Region
WHERE   q.Country IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY q.Country ,
        q.Region ,
        WeightingFactor
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the weighting factors do:

```
select country, quotecount,
       quotecount*1.0/sum(quotecount) over (partition by null) as allocp
from t
where country <> 'Blank'
```

To add these back in, join in the total:

```
select t.country, t.region, t.quotecount,
       (t.quotecount + allocp*b.BlankBQ) as AllocatedQC
from (select country, quotecount,
             quotecount*1.0/sum(quotecount) over (partition by region) as allocp
      from t
      where country <> 'Blank'
     ) t join
     (select sum(QuoteCount) as BlankBQ
      from t
      where country = 'Blank'
      group by region
     ) b
     on t.region = b.region
```